# Mongoose regex query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to find a single record that contains matches the name 'yoyo' using regex in a findOne query (incasesensitive regex). Instead of finding a match in the collection an error is thrown **MongooseError: Operation 'names.findOne()'buffering timed out after 10000ms**.

To my knowledge my query seems to not be applying the regex options of the query. But I am not sure why. Also maxTimeMS option doesn't seem to be working either not sure why.

`names.findOne({name: {$regex: 'yoyo',$options: 'i'}}, callback).maxTimeMS(2000).exec();`

Lets say the collection only contains the one record.
`{name:"YoYo",age:19}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `$regex` operator for mongoose. you should insert the regex in the `find()` query:

```
{name: {$regex: /yoyo/, $options: /*whatever regex options you need, like /g, etc */}}
```

That way the regex is delegated to the mongoDb engine and applied for the field you specify (e.g. "name").